# Entity Framework Core update one to many can't update list

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class TpmProjectEditDto : : FullAuditedEntity<long?, User>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TpmProjectContactLinkDto> TpmProjectContactLink { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TpmProjectClassLinkDto> TpmProjectClassLink { get; set; }
}


protected virtual async Task Update(TpmProjectEditDto input)
{
    var entity = await _entityRepository.GetAllIncluding(t=>t.TpmProjectContactLink,t=>t.TpmProjectClassLink,t => t.TpmProjectErrorLink).Where(t => t.Id == input.Id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    ObjectMapper.Map(input, entity);
    await _entityRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
}
```

`TpmProjectContactLink` and `TpmProjectClassLink` can't update - how to modify code Implement one-to-many update?

Comment: My two collections want to do differentiating updates (and database comparisons if the incoming collections and database collections are not compared to the new ones), but I can't implement them. Currently my approach can only update the TpmProjectEditDto other collections. Effective

Comment: Hard to say what isn't working with your code extract. Does UpdateAsync save the changes? Do you still have the entity attached to the context afetr having performed ObjectMapper.Map? I'd suggest having a look at the EF logs and see what happens on SQL level.

Comment: The instance of entity type 'TpmProjectClassLink' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.